# Adding driver to android devices kernel

Tags: android, kernel, driver, usb-otg

I would like to use a PCAN with my device.
I have the program for it, and an otg cable, but i need to install the driver first.
And i found a linux [driver](http://www.peak-system.com/fileadmin/media/linux/index.htm) on the manufacturers site.

I downloaded the kernel source, arm toolchain, and read a few sites about building and compiling but i havent find anything about adding driver.

So my question is, how can i add or install [this](http://www.peak-system.com/fileadmin/media/linux/index.htm) driver on android?
The device is galaxy tab 10.1 P7510.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does the driver come in source form, meaning the kernel would have to be compiled with the said driver in question? Details, can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: http://www.peak-system.com/fileadmin/media/linux/index.htm
this is the driver, i havent unpacked it yet, so i dont know.

Comment: Actually why are you not reading the page on the accompanying PDF to work out how to do this? It starts on page 13/14 of the PDF.

Answer (score 5):

Right, what you need to do is this:

- Unzip the tarball source
- Go into the respective directory of the source - `cd peak-linux-driver-7.7/` as quoted by the above PDF

> cd peak-linux-driver-x.y
>
> make clean
>
> make su -c “make install”

When the build completes, issue this command

> /sbin/modprobe pcan

However, having stated this, I do not see any reference to building with Android, so it looks like a fair bit of messing around with the source to get this to actually work on Android.

From what I can ascertain, this is more orientated towards the desktop PC only...

As is mentioned in a later comment clarifying this answer;  the kernel would need to be recompiled from source as an arm v7 or v8 target.
The part not mentioned was that it would also have to be statically linked to avoid requiring glibc in Android or bionic lib c in your computer.

Comment: thank you i will try, i think it might work, because the kernel is the same just they modified it a little bit

Comment: Remember this much, you are going to be cross compiling to native binary for Android - usually ARM chipset for this to work. You may have to cross-compile/recompile the kernel to add in the support for that for the driver to work....

Comment: Okay,when i get the device i will try, but i think i will stuck at the start, there is no "make" command in the android emulator. Do you know an alternative?

Comment: I tried but its not possible, i need to modify the kernel, do you know how to build a kernel adding a new driver to it? 
I downloaded the source code.